# goodman furnace /ac no y terminal on board

Tags: hvac

i live on a small budget and finally aquired an older goodman furnace (gmpn080-4)
and ac which were in very good condition out of a friends place and had only been used for 2-3 yrs. even the condenser outside was kept covered and secured when not in use . that said the units were in full working order together . they have been installed at my place all duct,furnace,a-coil,condenser (and charged) ,gas and main electric work is done .
but now i need some help on how to reconnect the low voltage wires .under normal circumstances i think i would have no problem but this furnace model has no Y terminal !!!
i only have 3 wires from the board W G R i bought a basic thermostat for heat/cool
ran a 5 wire of it and connected it at the thermostat as required also ran wire from condenser to furnace (airhandler). now i look at 5 wires from thermostat and the yellow and red from the condenser as well as the 3 wires red ,green and white from the furnace .missed the chance to be there during dismantling and i do not want to make a mistake and ruin what i have . where do they go ??? 
( i do not want to break the rules here by posting a link but pictures often tell more then words .there is an ebay listing that shows my exact board under the tittle : OEM Goodman Janitrol Furnace Control Circuit Board Panel B1809913S to see what i have )
i used to have grey hair but it turned white from googling this for days is there a way you could steer me to a wiring schematic that shows where i need to connect (assuming doubling up )the wires from the condenser to the board . the heat side i think i understand where to go. just not were i need to double the connection for the 2 wires from the condenser 
any help be truly appreciated and thanks in advance !!!

Comment: Please post pictures! If you can't upload them using the built-in function, upload them to [imgur](https://imgur.com) instead and put a link in the comments

Answer (score 1):

The furnace doesn't need a `Y` terminal, and in a lot of cases when it does have one, it's not connected to anything in the furnace.  Connect the wires from the thermostat as follows:

- Red connects to `R` in furnace and `R` on thermostat.
- White connects to `W` in furnace and `W` on thermostat.
- Green connects to `G` in furnace and `G` on thermostat.
- Yellow connects to the Red wire to the condensing unit.
- White wire from condensing unit connects to 24V common terminal of the transformer.

[image]

***Notes:***

- *The 24V common terminal of the transformer should be grounded to the chassis, as well as connected to PIN 6 of the Molex connector on the board.*
- *The "hot" 24V terminal of the transformer should be connected to PIN 3 of the Molex connector on the board.